# PHP removing forward slashes when concatenating

Tags: php, html

I'm making a script to display all images in a specific folder using PHP. However, when iterating through the for loop, my string holding the image destination (../images/uploads/imageName.png) is having the forward slashes removed (so in the actual image tag it looks like: .. images uploads imageName.php). The file destination displays correctly when echoing out the $num string. My script is displayed below:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$files = glob("../images/uploads/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
  $num = $files[$i];
  echo $num;
  echo '<img src"'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Are you developing on Windows? Aren't the printed slashes actually backslashes?

Comment: I am on Windows 10, and yes they are backslashes. My mistake :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing something here:

```
echo '<img src"'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Such as the `=` between `src` and the value

```
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

I am sure your image won't display without it regardless of what the path was....

> forward slashes removed (so in the actual image tag it looks like: .. images uploads imageName.php). The file destination displays correctly when echoing out the $num string.

What your probably seeing is how the browser is breaking when trying to figure out the HTML tag.  Because it's correct when you `echoing out the $num string` the value of the variable is correct, it's the tag that is breaking down.  PHP is not just going to magically do something to the value of a variable from one line to the next.

Cheers!

Comment: Curse my blind eyes!! Thanks a lot for the assist :D

Answer (score 2):

this will add a slash if your link doesn't have any slash at the end

```
if(substr($yourlinkvariable, -1) !== "/") {
$yourlinkvariable .= "/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with `str_replace()` function like so :

```
$num = str_replace(' ', '/', $files[$i]);
```

This should replace spaces by slash

Comment: Not a very good practice ! It could make problem in different environment ! However could be a workaround for this particular case.

Comment: No, it's made no difference. The actual num variable is correct, its only when concatenated into an <img> tag it does this